# Excel VBA Sort not 100% correct

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

New to the forum and hope someone can help.
Create a function to loop through a set of data row by row for sorting.
Firstly need to check if column 1 is not equal to 9999. If not insert into the appropriate row using column 1 as the sort criteria. If it equals 9999 then insert into the appropriate spot using column 3 and column 2.
The problem I'm encountering is that some row and not sort. I think its because as I'm cutting and pasting the row is missed. Below is my code and the sample data

```
Sub insertionTableSort()
'PURPOSE: loop through all employee and apply the sort as follows:
'1) Seniority <> 9999 Seniority number
'2) Seniority = 9999 sort start date then employee number
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

 
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Roster Applications")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("RosterRequest")  '## modify to your table name.
    Set tblRow = tbl.ListRows
    
    'Loop Through Every Row in Table
    For x = 2 To tbl.Range.Rows.Count - 1
        'Debug.Print x & ", " & tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 1).Value, tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 2).Value, tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 4).Value
            
        For y = 2 To tbl.Range.Rows.Count
            'seniroity = 9999
            If tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 1) = 9999 Then
                'sort by start date then Staff Num
                If tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 4) < tbl.DataBodyRange(y - 1, 4) And tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 2) < tbl.DataBodyRange(y - 1, 2) Then
                    tbl.ListRows(x).Range.Cut
                    tbl.ListRows(y - 1).Range.Insert
                    Exit For
                End If
            Else
               'seniroity <> 9999
               'sort by seniority
                If tbl.DataBodyRange(x, 1) < tbl.DataBodyRange(y - 1, 1) Then
                    tbl.ListRows(x).Range.Cut
                    tbl.ListRows(y - 1).Range.Insert
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

sample data after running the above
sorts well until this point where row 2 should be before row 1 and there are other examples

Data initially sort by Register No.
Errors highlighted in yellow

Finished Sort

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Are you sorting doing manual copy/pasting? Why can't you sort the normal way? Anyways, consider using an auxiliar column to put 99999 or not, depending on your ifs, sort by that column and then delete it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but tried and didn't work as the sort criteria is different if the seniority is 9999